# Classifying routes based on url parameter name in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I have 2 pages which can be accessed via these actions:

```
public class SearchEngineController : Controller
{
    [Route("/search/{k}")]
    public IActionResult Search(string k = "")
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ChannelController : Controller
{
    [Route("{name}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string name = "")
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now, when I search something with a key (`somekey`), I want to redirect to url `localhost:5000/search?k=somekey`

Because we're working with channels (like Youtube's channels), so we need to classify the channel names, it should be unique. Example, a channel with a name `mobifone` can be accessed through `localhost:5000/mobifone`.

Everything may look ok until the `name` parameter (inside the `Index` action) cannot classify when a searched request is called. So, everytime I type `localhost:5000/search?k=somekey`, it will hit the `Index` action.

So, my temporary solution looks like this:

```
public class ChannelController : Controller
{
    [Route("{name}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string name = "")
    {
        if (name.ToLower() == "search")
        {
            // ~/Views/Shared/Search.cshtml
            return View("Search");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

It *may* solve the problem but.... I don't like it. Because I don't want to nest and excute the search query inside `ChannelController`. It's not a part of channel. A channel may contain:

```
- Id
- Name
- DisplayName
- FounderId
- ...
```

In the middleware, `_channelManager` shouldn't have a searched engine member which can return *everything in the world*, such as:

```
- Channel information
- List of channels
- User profile
- A post content
- List of posts
- ...
```

Is there any way better than mine?

Comment: Works for me when removing both `/` and `{k}`  from ` [Route("/search/{k}")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not actually using a correct route. You've defined the search route as "/search/{k}", which then means that you need something like `/search/somekey` to actually hit it. What you're requesting is `/search?k=somekey`, which doesn't match the search route, and is likely simply falling back to your default route, which just so happens to be this `ChannelController.Index` action. If you're wanting to pass the `k` param via the querystring, then you should remove it from the route definition, i.e. `[Route("/search")]`.